# Ejecutar función bash en terminal abierta cada cierto tiempo o al hacer focus (iterm2)

Tags: bash, macos

estoy creando una porción de código en bash que abre terminales en light o dark mode dependiendo del perfil que tenga actualmente el sistema (macos). Actualmente funciona, pero funciona solo al momento de abrirlas. Como es conocido en mac el perfil cambia de light a dark automáticamente según la hora entonces lo que necesito es detectar ese cambio para que se haga automáticamente en las terminales actualmente abiertas.

Para eso se me ocurre ejecutar una función verificadora cada cierto tiempo que lance la función que cambia el modo o capturar el evento cuando se hace focus a la ventana (iterm2) y ejecutar dicha corroboración.

Qué opciones tengo para lograr alguna de las 2 en bash?

*Especial mención en que debo poder seguir utilizando la instancia de terminal normalmente y que el proceso se debe ejecutar en paralelo pero afectar esa ventana.

Comment: Usa una tarea `cron`.

Comment: Qué es eso?????